# CSS used to build a feature works, but breaks the CSS used to build the site

Tags: css, html

I'm building a page on a site that was made using CSS and I'm using CSS to style the page. When I look at a dummy html page using the CSS it does exactly as I need i.e. it places an image in the accordian, then has the text next to the image. However once I confirm it on the site, it breaks the page, as if the CSS I've used has interfered with the CSS used to make the actual website that I'm building on. I tried to change the div and img to  but it moves the accordian and the text is no longer next to the image. As you can probably guess I am a CSS noob, so any help appreciated.

This happened after I added a Div and an Img parameter.

Here's the CSS:

```
img{
    display:inline-block;
    width:211px;
    height:146px;
    border:1px solid white;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
}

div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:311px;
}
```

And the code for the web page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="accordion vertical">
          <section id="vertabout">
              <h2><a href="#vertabout">Tutor-Led Course</a></h2>
              <img src="http://bathnes.learningpool.com/draftfile.php/2592/user/draft/826412532/TutorLedCourse.jpg" height="134" width="208" />
<div>To view the tutor-led course information, please click <a href="http://bathnes.learningpool.com/course/view.php?id=187">here</a></div>
<p><strong>IT Courses - Excel 2010 Basic</strong></p>
          </section>
          <section id="vertservices">
              <h2><a href="#vertservices">E-Learning Module</a></h2>
                      <p><p><img src="http://bathnes.learningpool.com/draftfile.php/2592/user/draft/826412532/RelatedELearning.jpg" height="146" width="211" /> </p></p>
          </section>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Tidied up the page, removed CSS that didn't need to be there.

Comment: Tip: target the elements more in more detail, instead of having img { look_like_this } have img.thisImage { look_like_this }, .thisImage means class="thisImage". The same goes for div as they are one of the elements you will be using the most.

Comment: Create a class for the **img** and **div** rules you have at the bottom. Then they will not overwrite (due to the cascade) all of your img and div's in your page?

Comment: Hi, I tried creating a class for the image/div rules. However for some reason it moved the entire accordion towards the center of the page, which broke the text placement next to the image.

Comment: If I changed img and div to say, img.QQQ and div.EEE, how would I need to use those in the HTML. Perhaps it's something that I've done wrong when trying to get the HTML to use the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to target all divs on the page, just the div inside the `accordion`. If that's the only div/img in the accordion, change the above code to

```
.accordion img{
    display:inline-block;
    width:211px;
    height:146px;
    border:1px solid white;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.accordion div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:311px;
}
```

Comment: No probs, you're welcome. You've just seen an example of how powerful CSS can be, with its ability to target specific elements.