# CSS Syntax for HTML - Using img.example element in my html

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS, however the elements need a unique class, or they interfere with the CSS used to create the website I'm using it on.

```
img{
    display:inline-block;
    width:211px;
    height:146px;
    border:1px solid white;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
}

div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:311px;
}
```

I need to make them unique classes like:

```
img.example{
    display:inline-block;
    width:211px;
    height:146px;
    border:1px solid white;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
}

div.example2{
    display:inline-block;
    width:311px;
}
```

So to start with, is that the correct way to make them classes?

If it is, how do I then apply them to the "**" sections of this HTML? The div becomes div.example2 ? How about using the img.example ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="accordion vertical">
          <section id="vertabout">
              <h2><a href="#vertabout">Tutor-Led Course</a></h2>


**<img src="http://bathnes.learningpool.com/draftfile.php/2592/user/draft/826412532/TutorLedCourse.jpg" height="134" width="208" />**
**<div>To view the tutor-led course information, please click <a href="http://bathnes.learningpool.com/course/view.php?id=187">here</a></div>**
<p><strong>IT Courses - Excel 2010 Basic</strong></p>
          </section>
          <section id="vertservices">
              <h2><a href="#vertservices">E-Learning Module</a></h2>
                      <p><p><img src="http://bathnes.learningpool.com/draftfile.php/2592/user/draft/826412532/RelatedELearning.jpg" height="146" width="211" /> </p></p>
          </section>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Apologies, but I am terrible with CSS and HTML :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435365/css-used-to-build-a-feature-works-but-breaks-the-css-used-to-build-the-site

Answer (score 2):

That is the proper way to select a tag with a class, but you need to add the classes.

```
<img src="http://bathnes.learningpool.com/draftfile.php/2592/user/draft/826412532/TutorLedCourse.jpg" 
    height="134" width="208" class="example"/>
<div class="example2">To view the tutor-led course information, please click <a href="http://bathnes.learningpool.com/course/view.php?id=187">here</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helped. Just one more small issue, the text is to the right of the image as I want it, but it's like []__ so it's [] = an image __ = where the text is. When I make a dummy html page and try it, the text is []''' where [] is the image and ''' is the text. Any idea why it's doing this? (I'd like the text to be next to the top of the image, as in the second example.)